# Is there an excel formula that looks at a column of duplicates and returns the value next to the lower duplicate for the whole column?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2016

In Excel, for the below table, I need a formula that I can drag down in Column C. It would look at Column A, find a duplicate, then bring the lower value of the duplicate from Column B associated with Column A. For example Apple has 2 values 104 and 105, hence it places 104 in Column C.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 105 | FORMULA |
| Apple | 104 | 104 |
| Mango | 111 |  |
| Pear | 115 |  |
| Pear | 114 | 114 |
| Banana | 201 |  |

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this with the *topmost* value from Column B, you could just use [a `VLOOKUP` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1), like so:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

So, how can we invert this?  Well, if you have [excel-365](/questions/tagged/excel-365) or [excel-2021](/questions/tagged/excel-2021), then you can use [the `XLOOKUP` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) instead:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2, A:A, B:B, FALSE, NA(), 0, -1)
```

(That final `-1` is the bit that tells it *“Start searching from the bottom”*)

If you *don't* have access to the `XLOOKUP` function, then you probably need to either [Invert the Array with `Offset`](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/444529-how-to-reverse-a-range-array.html), or do something fancy with [the `AGGREGATE` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) to grab the Maximum Row-value where that matches the current input.

Answer (score 0):

Using COUNTIF and MINIFS.  This will put the minimum value of the value in Column A on the last version of that value and only if it is duplicated:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=COUNTIF(A:A,A1),COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1),MINIFS(B:B,A:A,A1),"")
```

[image]

If instead you want to put the value next to the minimum value for that criteria one can use:

```
=IF(AND(MINIFS(B:B,A:A,A1)=B1,COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1),B1,"")
```

instead.

If one does not have MINIFS(), Replace the `MINIFS(B:B,A:A,A1)` with `AGGREGATE(15,7,B:B/(A:A=A1),1)`

Comment: I checked MINIFS and it does not seem to work in Excel 2016, would you happen to know how =IF(AND(MINIFS(B:B,A:A,A1)=B1,COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1),B1,"") can be modified to use MIN(IF( instead?

Comment: @beckythelearner see edit.